# iOS 13 Xcode how to remove QuickType on UIKeyboard ( auto complete / auto suggest )

Tags: ios, autocomplete, uikeyboard, autosuggest

UIKeyboard with QuickType!

It is bad to know that there is no sufficient space of  screen on iPhone devices, now apple has been taken more room by adding QuickType. How can I  remove it for items that do not need quicktype's auto complete, auto suggest?

Comment: This worked! textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can set the autocorrectionType to NO. Its an existing iOS property so won't break in any previous/current versions of iOS;

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked brilliant! Hope you are well too! I am on iOS8 + Yosemite

Comment: Note that this only prevents the display of suggestions.  If you need to prevent QuickType from learning for security reasons, this setting will not prevent learning on the iOS 8 GM seed.

Comment: @WaltSellers are you aware of any technique that disables this learning system?

Comment: @Leon No, I am not aware of any technique for disabling QuickType's learning. Sorry.

Comment: @WaltSellers Do you think it could be abused? I think we may assume that Apple doesn't learn from a password field which takes care of the security risk of QuickType.

Comment: @WaltSellers - If your worried - as an end user you can turn `predictive` off in the `keyboard settings` in `general` - again no evidence that apple removes the learning when off.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge - a few quick tests easily show that QuickType does still learn when the "Predictive" option is turned off.

Comment: Great but I WANT the quicktype keyboard. I DONT want the red lines under suggestions ... how can these be achieved at the same time?

Comment: UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo is not working in iphone 6 - iOS 8.1

Comment: It doesn't work on iPad.