# Disable iOS8 Quicktype Keyboard programmatically on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I'm trying to update an app for iOS8, which has a chat interface, but the new Quicktype keyboard hides the text view, so I would like to turn it off programmatically or in interface builder.

Is it possible somehow or only the users can turn it off in the device settings?

I know there is a question/answer which solves this problem with a `UITextfield`, but I need to do it with a `UITextView`.

Comment: I don't know whether you can or not, but it doesn't seem like a good idea anyway. I use an app that does something similar on Android, and it's really frustrating. I think it's better to work around it to allow the user to decide whether they want those suggestions there or not.

Comment: @Hassan My problem is, that it destroys my UI, so I wanna hide/disable any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it be better if you could move the text view up to accommodate the keyboard, rather than hide the suggestions? Again, I apologize because I don't actually know how to do that, I was only making a friendly suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5324303/377628). Set up the notification method, and move the text view accordingly when the height of the keyboard changes. I don't know if this would work in iOS 8 though.

Comment: @Hassan , thank you. I think it would be good. My solution is something like the iMessage, and it does what you said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios8 xcode how to remove QuickType on UIKeyboard ( auto complete / auto suggest )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031362/ios8-xcode-how-to-remove-quicktype-on-uikeyboard-auto-complete-auto-suggest)

Comment: Terrible. Why would people want to use your app for chat, when you disable autocomplete and autocorrect? Fix your app to work correctly.

Comment: Some kind of built-in keyboard (e.g. Japanese) has Quicktype like completion view from iOS5. http://www.macstories.net/news/hack-brings-auto-correct-bar-to-default-ios-5-keyboard/. You should not predicate the size of keyboard anyway.

Comment: @Hassan, in my case i cant move the text view since there is no room on the 4S small screen to fit all the views.  I had to disable it.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You may disable the keyboard suggestions / autocomplete / QuickType for a UITextView which can block the text on smaller screens like the 4S as shown in this example

with the following line:

```
myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

[image] [image]

And further if youd like to do this only on a specific screen such as targeting the 4S

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    if (screenHeight == 568) {
        // iphone 5 screen
    }
    else if (screenHeight < 568) {
       // smaller than iphone 5 screen thus 4s
    }
}
```

Comment: UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo is not working in iphone 6 - iOS 8.1

Comment: @iGW when i did this after the UITextView or UITextField was already firstResponder it didn't work for me either. Try either setting it prior to that, or triggering resign and becomeFirstResponder (the former obviously being the "correct" and more appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: How do I get the reference to the textView, given a UIWebView?

Comment: FYI, for Swift the code is textField.autocorrectionType = .No

Comment: For any subclass of `Responder` that implements `UIKeyInput`, the getter method for this variable can be implemented to return `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo` to achieve the same effect when not using a `UITextField`.

Answer (score 53):

For completeness sake I would like to add that you can also do this in the `Interface Builder`.

To disable Keyboard Suggestions on `UITextField` or `UITextView` — in the `Attributes Inspector` set `Correction` to `No` .

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me. The QuickType suggestion still displayed for my keyboard when I did this. But the programmatic answer did work for me.

Comment: It's weird that this didn't work for you because essentially what it does is set `autocorrectionType` to `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`. The same thing you do in code. Could you doublecheck, and if the behaviour doesn't change tell me what versions of Xcode and iOS are you using?

Comment: I have this set to No on my project, and it still showed up on the Swype custom keyboard.

Comment: I have not found a way to get that Swype keyboard to turn off that part. Incidentally, that thing is MASSIVE. I'll have to make my code query the size of it and adjust its animation for that.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a UITextView category class with the following method:

```
- (void)disableQuickTypeBar:(BOOL)disable
{
    self.autocorrectionType = disable ? UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo : UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;

    if (self.isFirstResponder) {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

I wish there was a cleaner approach tho. Also, it assumes the auto-correction mode was `Default`, which may not be always true for every text view.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2:

```
myUITextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.x:

```
myUTTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use:

```
textView.autocorrectionType = .no
```

but I've also noticed people struggling with actually making the autocomplete bar swap out, since if the textView is already the firstResponder when you change its autocorrectionType, it won't update the keyboard. Instead of trying to resign and reassign the firstResponder status to the textView to effect the change, you can simply call:

```
textView.reloadInputViews()
```

and that should hide the autocomplete bar. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621110-reloadinputviews