# Why do iPhone 6 Plus keyboards look different on my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikeyboard, iphone-6-plus

It may seem a bit of a simple or unusual question, but I've noticed that there are two different sizes of keyboard in iPhone 6 Plus.

My app, built with Xcode, has a keyboard which is massive on an iPhone 6 Plus and small when running other apps.

[image: Small Keyboard in other apps]

The one above is from other iPhone apps on the 6+, and the one below from my app.

[image: My App's Keyboard]

Is there anyway to select which keyboard to use?

Answer (score 7):

The actual problem here is that your app is running in scaled-up mode. What you need to do is provide a specific launch image so that the OS knows that your app works correctly without scaling on bigger screens like the the 6 and 6 Plus.

There are numerous questions about this on stack overflow. Who can add a link to a great answer to my posting?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this apparent keyboard size difference with a simple demo app. I'm using Xcode 7.3.1, iOS9.3 (13E230), iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s on the simulator. Anyone willing to share a simple demo app that shows the `larger` keyboard size?

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the fact that the app is a ScaleUp app (the app is scaled to the larger iPhones)
[iPhone 6 & iPhone 6 Plus: A tale of scale](http://sixcolors.com/post/2014/09/iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-a-tale-of-scale/)

Answer (score 0):

The quicktype keyboard is on any iOS 8 device. It can be disabled by turning off auto correction as shown here

[Disable iOS8 Quicktype Keyboard programmatically on UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951274/disable-ios8-quicktype-keyboard-programmatically-on-uitextview)

Additionally your app will be scaled up on larger phones if you do not provide the correct launch image

[How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Comment: This question is not about hiding or showing Quicktype. Please take a look at the images posted by the OP.

Comment: Do launch images even matter?

Comment: yes. but there are some ways around it in the post I provided about native resolution apps.

Comment: I'm not referring to the quick type feature, but to the different size of the keys and their spacing.