# How do you get rid of the standard inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

In iOS, if you create a UIView that implements UIKeyInput, you can get a keyboard by becoming first responder. When that keyboard appears, it has a system defined inputAccessoryView, like this:

[image]

How do I make this go away, and get a bare keyboard?

Comment: Did you try setting the `autocorrectionType`? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: This was not quite a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951274/disable-ios8-quicktype-keyboard-programmatically-on-uitextview. That question referred to UITextView, while this one deals with UIViews that implement keyboard input. The clue is there, though: Adopt UITextInputTraits in your view, provide your own definition of autocorrectionType, then set it to UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo.

Comment: The clue was in my comment, was it not?

Comment: Yes, and in the duplicate. I up voted your comment. :)