# How i hide a top keyboard bar in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm a beginner ios developer. I'm trying hide "shortcut keyboard bar" on iOS keyboard with unsuccessful.
Bellow is my code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
      UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [textField inputAssistantItem];
      item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
      item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
}
```

I did hide the assistant bar buttons with setting autocorretionType, but the top bar with action button (ok, done, ...) don't hide.

[image]

Can someone help me out?
Tks.

Comment: That isn't natural for an iOS keyboard, you must be adding that bar to the keyboard.. right?

Comment: Show what you did to display this top bar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26500983/653513

Comment: Thank you, @MSU_Bulldog and @shpasta! I was continue the developing a iOS app and i'm complete new :(
So i checked the project and saw it uses the [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager).
To disable the bar was need set a property like this:
    textField.inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] init];

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
YourTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Comment: This will remove the view that bottom of marked rectangle in above picture, he wants remove `inputAccessoryview` not autoCorrection view

Answer (score 3):

If your project is using `IQKeyboardManager`, then to get rid of that top bar, you can use  `IQKeyboardManager.shared().disabledToolbarClasses.add(YourViewController.self)`

Comment: It is `IQKeyboardManager.shared.disabledToolbarClasses.append(YourViewController.self)` in IQKeyboardManagerSwift v6.4.2

Answer (score 2):

remove `inputAccessoryView` from your `UITextField`

```
yourTextField.inputAccessoryview = nil
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: add empty View

```
yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
```