# Disable UITextView suggestions but keep auto-correction

Tags: ios, uitextview

I would like to disable suggestions for UITextView but keep the auto-correct.

By setting the autocorrectionType to NO will hide the suggestions but will disable the auto-correct option as well.

Here is the example I want to achieve
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26500983

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy - this doesn't work for UITextView. May work for UITextField

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: @rmaddy it still shows the suggestions bar on the top of the keyboard. the only way to hide it is to go to device's settings and disable predictive mode